# Trying to alternate between GridView & ListView leaving artifacts

Tags: android, listview, gridview

I have an app whose default style is to present data in a GridView. When the user presses the Menu button they can choose to present the data as a ListView.

The problem is that once the first switch happens, it's as though the ListView is simply superimposed above the GridView. The GridView layout doesn't go away. I have to scroll with my finger a little bit before it disappears.

What I'm doing is basically setting another setContentView call to my XML file that defines the ListView. It's not just a simple matter of changing the adapters.

I am guessing that I need to completely destroy or remove my GridView--but how do I do this? Note that if I switch from ListView to GridView the problem remains.

Comment: You are replacing the view with 'setContentView(int)', correct? Have you tried call the 'invalidate()' method of the new view?

Comment: That is correct. I just tried calling invalidate() on the new view, and then, on the old view. That did not work.

Answer (score 3):

Consider putting both in a `ViewFlipper`, rather than using `setContentView()`.

Answer (score 1):

for list

`gridview.setNumColumns(1);`

and for grid

`gridview.setNumColumns(2);`

Answer (score 0):

What about playing with visibility?
When List is selected in menu, make gridview visibility to 'GONE',and list to 'VISIBLE'
and vice versa when Grid is selected in menu

Comment: I was using this with FragmentActivity before learning about `ViewFlipper` from @CommonsWare s answer. This was working fine without any perfomance issues.